# Python CGI returns correct text to curl but browsers display trailing zero

Tags: python, apache, curl, cgi

I wrote this simple CGI app in Python 3:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.4

print("Content-type: text/html\n")

print("AAAA")
```

- If I go to the URL with any browser, I get a page showing this: "AAAA 0". It displays exactly this in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on a Mac and Safari on an iPhone. Changing the "AAAA" to anything else changes the output accordingly in all browsers, but the trailing "0" always remains in every browser.
- The browser's "view source" always shows the expected string+newline (which the browser treats as a space, of course) followed by an unexpected 0:

  ```
  AAAA
  0
  ```
- directly executing it from the server's command line (./foo.py | hex) and viewing the output with a hex editor produced the expected output: both header and content lines, with the content line as 41 41 41 0A ("AAAA\n")
- using curl from both my Mac laptop and from the Linux server's command line likewise produces exactly the hex output I expect: 41 41 41 41 0A
- curl on any (tested) platform shows no trailing zero. All browsers on all platforms DO show a trailing zero.
- If I remove the second "print" statement, leaving only the one "print" statement for the header, the trailing "0" disappears in all browsers, leaving only a blank page, but if I put any print statement after the header print, a trailing zero will appear in all browsers but not in any curl. Even an empty "print()" produces an empty first line (the newline, I'm sure) followed by a "0" on the second line of the "view source". If I ADD more print lines, inserting the proper doctype & html, the trailing zero shows up after the end-html tag in the source. If I print anything other than the header, a trailing zero shows up in the browser source.
- Changing to Python3.2 made no difference
- So, trying to make curl spoof a browser, I added the "user-agent" from a couple of browsers. No difference. Curl still always shows what I expect it to show and all the browsers still display a trailing zero.
- Retyping the simple code (not copying and pasting) to make sure there are no invisible characters produces the same results (and hex view of the Python source, of the output from running it on the server, and the output obtained by curl all show no extra characters).
- This is shared hosting using Apache+CGI, and I haven't changed any Apache files or created any .htaccess files.
- I could use mod_wsgi, which works fine, if this were for production, but it's for learning. I'm trying to teach kids how to use low-level CGI, having them manually extract GET data from ENV vars, etc., so they can see what's going on underneath before moving up to more pre-built functionality (cgi module, then WSGI, then Flask, etc.) The point is to understand what's going on, but I don't.

So, can anybody tell me what's going on here in this most basic of web apps? Where is that "0" coming from (successful status code?), and why does it show up in browser source but not in curl? And, most importantly, how do I get rid of it?

UPDATE:
This problem only occurs when my browser is on a phone using ATT's "LTE" for data, or any browser accessing the Web via tethering to ATT's "LTE". If I walk my phone into the house, it switches over to Comcast/Wifi, refresh the browser page and "AAAA 0" turns into "AAAA". Walk out of the house (out of wifi range), refresh using LTE, and "AAAA" turns back into "AAAA 0". Same happens with browser on laptop.

So, here's the telnet output when the laptop is tethered and showing "AAAA 0" in all browsers (no problem I can see, just as in curl):

```
> telnet my.domain.com 80
Trying 100.99.98.97...
Connected to my.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /temp.py HTTP/1.0
Host: my.domain.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 23:28:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding

AAAA
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Just for kicks, throw a `sys.exit(1)` at the end of the script. See if a 1 gets printed instead.

Comment: Hey, that was a good guess, but, no, with sys.exit(1) as its last line, it still shows a trailing zero in a browser and no trailing anything in curl.

Comment: Try running `curl --ignore-content-length`. Does the `0` show up when you do?

Comment: Does your apache run in a chroot jail? If so, can you try to run the CGI script by hand while inside the chroot?

Comment: Try writing a trivial sh CGI: `#!/bin/sh` / `echo "content-type: text/html"` / `echo ""` / `echo "AAAA"`. How does that CGI behave?

Comment: Robᵩ, I can curl with or without --ignore-content-length and it works properly either way, meaning no trailing 0

Comment: Robᵩ, when I write it in sh instead, I still get the same behavior: "AAAA 0" from the browser and "AAAA" from curl. Thanks for the suggestion. I guess that rules out Python as the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trailing '0' is likely to be from the chunked response format, but browsers shouldn't be showing it.

If you add a 'Content-Length' header of the correct size for the response, it by rights should go away, because Apache wouldn't then use chunked response as that is only used where the length is not known.

What is the complete output you get if you use 'telnet' to connect to the server and issue the request manually.

```
telnet server-hostname 80
```

Then enter:

```
GET /some/url HTTP/1.0
Host: virtual-hostname
```

with an extra blank line after that.

Comment: When I do that, it responds with an error 503 page from nginx stating that the website has not been set up. The shared hosting is from WebFaction, and if I recall correctly, they have an nginx server in front, which will serve static .html pages directly or will forward to an Apache instance for dynamic pages such as a CGI invocation or (your excellent) mod_wsgi. The above telnet command apparently isn't getting past nginx, even if I request the static homepage.

Comment: Graham, I tried your experiment and added a content-length header. As you surmised, the problem went away. It's annoying to have to do this, because we can't simply print as we go but will have to generate the output, concatenate it, measure it, and then output the headers, but we were going to get to that anyway with mod_wsgi, so oh, well. I still wonder what's going on and why it shows up in all browsers and not in curl.

Comment: Can you add to your question the complete output you got from the telnet test without a content length. Then I can perhaps see why.

Comment: Graham, as I said above, your telnet test never reaches Apache. Instead, nginx returns the identical very long placeholder page (HTML+CSS: "This website has not been set up....") no matter what /some/url I give it (properly working static .html pages, CGI with or without content-length, other subdomains, etc.)
"HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 05 Sep 2014 06:20:48 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3282
Connection: close
ETag: "51276bc2-cd2"
<!DOCTYPE....
....Connection closed by foreign host." 
I don't know how to reach Apache with telnet.

Comment: Your system is likely using virtual hosts then. See amended command to telnet above. Specifically, need to send the Host header giving the name of the virtual host.